# How can I test File I/O in containerized integration tests in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I'm building a spring boot application; for Integration Testing I'm running docker, with a mysql database and test data, I'm mocking another service that it needs to communicate with.

All of this works fine.
My problem however is that I require files on the file system that the app can read. The metadata for these files is stored in the database.

In the real world, normally what happens is there is a shared storage that the application pods use between them. 
When a new record appears in the database an instance of the app will read the reccord, contact artifactory if the file doesn't already exist in the storage (which appears as a normal folder in `/srv/my-app/my-files` or something similar) and download it.
This poses a problem for me as I require all the files to be on the file system in order to run the tests. The real files are too big, and it would take too long to query the database, download them from artifactory (I don't want to do that anyway), etc...
I would like to make some dummy files available for the app to use, maybe 3 or 4 files with a couple of rows of text in.
Right now my database test data is stored in json files in the project in `/test/resources/datasets`
Is there some way to define a folder path and a couple of dummy files that will be placed there when the app container spins up for testing?

Comment: Why don't you integrate these files in the test image?

Comment: Yes, How can I go about doing that? what should I look at? The docker image? Then I need to add them in the jenkins build or something??  When I search for a solution the only results I get are related to test databases. I'm really clueless here, don't even know what to search for.